# Stratum on subset of data: drop if too small?

Tags: r, pca, genetics, stratification

We have genotype data for ~20000 samples with 4 principal components and 10 strata - study centres. Formula for an example analysis would be:

```
glm(x ~ strata+pc1+pc2+pc3+pc4+SNP)
```

`x` - can be binary or continuous variable.

Some variables are not complete, e.g.: `x1` might have 4000 complete samples and `x2` can have 15000. After subsetting, some strata become too small - 10 vs 200, 0 vs 0, 0 vs 150.

Do we keep strata in the formula or drop them? Do we recalculate principal components for each subset?